# Need to store the output of an API into a .csv file

Tags: powershell

I am unable to store the values of the `Invoke-WebRequest` in a single line to a .csv file.

I wanted to store the weather details into a pipe delimited .csv file in the below format:

```
TimeStamp|Temperature|RH
```

Expected Result:

```
TIME_HK|HonkKong.Temperature|HonkKong.RH
```

```
$TIME = Get-Date
$TIME_HK = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId($TIME, [System.TimeZoneInfo]::Local.Id, 'China Standard Time')
$UnixTimeStamp = [System.Math]::Truncate((Get-Date -Date $TIME_HK -UFormat %s))
$URL = "http://my.weather.gov.hk/wxinfo/json/one_json.xml?_=" + $UnixTimeStamp
$Weather = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $URL -UseBasicParsing
$HonkKong = $Weather.hko
```

[image: Details of Actual and Expected results]

Comment: In your question you are missing the csv writting code. Are you using [Sistem.IO.File.WriteAllText()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_File_WriteAllText_System_String_System_String_)?

Comment: How do you create the csv? It should work like you expect with the command export-csv. Example:`$HonkKong | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "|" -Path "yourpath.csv"`

Comment: I used Add-Content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$Weather.hko | Export-Csv "out.csv"
```

If needed, you can set the delimiter via `-Delimiter ";"`.

```
 > Get-Content .\out.csv
 "BulletinTime","Temperature","RH","HomeMaxTemperature","HomeMinTemperature"
 "201907021440","29.1","86","32","26"
```

If you want to append information you can use the `-Append` switch.

Comment: I want to continuously store the value and also the time format I have to change

Comment: what resolution do you need?

Comment: I am going to schedule that script, every 5 minutes the script has to run and append the values to the csv. Thats the resolution I am looking for

Comment: OP said the delimiter used was `|`, not `;`, so it should be `-Delimiter "|"`